# System image folder in config.ini doesn't exist

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin

Recently I installed Xamarin and the Android SDK in order to mess around with Android development. After spending all day fixing errors before writing a single line of code, this one has me stumped. I haven't found a solution anywhere on the internet.

[image]

I have installed the emulator and I have downloaded several system images. I have searched for this config.ini but didn't find which one the error seemed to be referencing. I can build the solution just fine but when I try to debug it just says "There were deployment errors", and in the output window just says "Error: cancelled."

Is there any way to solve this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Well did you check this? https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/msft-android-emulator and this https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/debugging/debug-on-emulator/visual-studio-android-emulator/

Comment: @G.hakim I can't say I did. I didn't think of trying a different emulator altogether, in all honestly. I'm installing it now, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @G.hakim ok I installed that, and it completely broke the SDK installation. It says the SDK folder doesn't contain adb.exe, when it does. Nothing I do will convince it otherwise. I reinstalled Xamarin just in case, to no avail. I uninstalled the microsoft emulator and reinstalled Xamarin. Still just as broken.

Comment: Downloading Microsoft vs emulators cannot break the sdk it might have highlighted that issue may be there is something wrong with your sdk can you try redownloading it?

Comment: The SDK was working fine before I did that. For whatever reason it took 2 reinstalls to fix the issue but it was resolved in the end, along with this one. It also fixed my original question, so uh... the solution is keep reinstalling until it works, I guess?

Comment: Actually, the problem was with the installation you probably missed something or the other which could be causing the issue, in any case, I am answering the question with how you ended up solving the issue feel free to correct it if i write something wrong

Answer (score 5):

So I come across the same error message on my device manager. I solved it with following step:

1. Go to your `~\.android\avd`. There should be a folder named
   `[YourDeviceName].avd`. For my case it was Nexus_5X_API_28_x86.avd.
2. Inside the folder there should be a config.ini. Look for a property
   named `image.sysdir.1`. Mine was `image.sysdir.1=system-images\android-28\google_apis_playstore\x86\`.
   Make sure the your have properly downloaded such image in
   `%ANDROID_HOME%\system-images`.

For me, it seems that I have installed Android SDK twice in two different locations with Android Studio & Visual Studio Xamarin installation, and they have messed up my device manager. So I uninstalled one and moved the images and it worked fine then. While this is probably a year too late for OP, I hope this could help someone in the future.

Comment: To find the folder mentioned in step 1, right-click the device row and choose "Reveal in Explorer".

Answer (score 3):

I just had the same issue.

#### You solve this problem like this:

1. Select the corresponding Android emulator device
2. Hit the Ellipsis character at the upper right corner of Android Device Manager
3. Select "Download system image" menu item

This will download the missing system images for your Android emulator.

Here are some screenshots, depicting the solution (they're in German):

[image: Android Device Manager - Download System Image menu item]

[image: Android Device Manager - Download progress]

I suspect Microsoft didn't add these because they're not courtesy of Google. You need to accept Google's license terms when downloading the images.